# Java Collection:Collection framework:Less bucket is good to store object in collection or large number of bucket?

Tags: java, collections, equals, hashcode

Here i just want to ask one question which i faced in Java interview.
Question was like how hashmap works.I explained and answered all following questions.But i stuck at one question,which was:
Is it better to have more bucket of objects in collection or less bucket?and why? Please help me here with your view

Comment: @user2310289:I told them that it will be better to have more proper hashcode method so that every time unique hash code can be generated and new bucket will be created for every object.But in this case it will also take more time to locate the bucket other way is if we develop hashcode method in such a way that it will return same hashcode for all the objects then also again it will consume more time with equals method to search object in single bucket.After this discussion final conclusion was we should not have separate bucket for each object and having single bucket is also not efficient.

Comment: @Rohan: It is often helpful to have the number of buckets be large enough that some buckets are unused, but not a totally disproportionate number.  Many computers have a limited amount of cache space, and so having a hash table that contains 256 buckets, some of which have half a dozen items, may outperform a table with 1,048,576 buckets, the vast majority of which have no items and none of which have more than one, especially if looking for many items that aren't in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best HashMap = Unique Ids - one bucket for one object - fastest access to object when you know the key.

Comment: But if there is one bucket for one object then also it will consume time to search the bucket of specific hash code as there can be large number of bucket presents.

Comment: there's no need need to search - Hash map provide you instant access to bucket via hash code, just as array index.

Comment: ok...thanks i was not aware of this instant access concept.